# How to expand $\frac{1}{n^a(n+k)^b}$ using partial fraction decomposition?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, partial-fractions

Is it possible to decompose $\displaystyle\frac{1}{n^a(n+k)^b}$ into finite summation?

where $a,b,n,k\in Z^{+}$ and $a+b$ is odd.

What I tried is converting the fraction to double integral:

$\displaystyle\frac{(-1)^{a+b}}{(a-1)!(b-1)!}\int_0^1\int_0^1 x^{n-1}y^{n+k-1}\ln^{a-1}(x)\ln^{b-1}(y)dxdy$ which I found useless.

Any method or reference is much appreciated.

Comment: Can I ask what kind of finite summation do you want?

Comment: @JetfiRex Like the limits of the sum have to be finite ( not infinity)

Comment: ugh... sorry, could you give me an example?

Comment: @JetfiRex $\sum_{n=a}^b$ where a,b are positive integers,

Comment: As a single term, the expression is already a "finite summation" in the sense you have defined.  The notion of "partial fraction decomposition" perhaps leads to a more challenging problem.  Perhaps you could illustrate what you want with the simplest case $a=2$ and $b=1$?

Comment: @hardmath I found the answer and I posted it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this [paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/285AFC7710AE96D179D8ED067B35E076/S0013091500019088a.pdf/explicit_evaluation_of_euler_sums.pdf), page 284, we have

$$\frac{1}{x^s(1-x)^t}=\sum_{j=1}^s\binom{s+t-j-1}{s-j}\frac1{x^j}+\sum_{j=1}^s\binom{s+t-j-1}{t-j}\frac1{(1-x)^j},$$

where $s,t \ge0, s+t\ge1.$

Replacing $x$ with $-x/n$ gives

$$\frac{(-n)^s}{x^s(1+x/n)^t}=\sum_{j=1}^s\binom{s+t-j-1}{s-j}\frac{(-n)^j}{x^j}+\sum_{j=1}^s\binom{s+t-j-1}{t-j}\frac1{(1+x/n)^j},$$

or

$$\frac{1}{x^s(n+x)^t}=\sum_{j=1}^s\binom{s+t-j-1}{s-j}\frac{(-1)^{s+j}}{n^{s+t-j}x^j}+\sum_{j=1}^s\binom{s+t-j-1}{t-j}\frac{(-1)^s}{n^{s+t-j}(n+x)^j}.$$

Answer (score 5):

Polynomials $P(x)=x^a$ and $Q(x)=(x+k)^b$ are coprime for $k \ne 0$, so by [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity_and_extended_GCD_algorithm) there exist $A(x),B(x)$ with $\deg A \lt b, \deg B \lt a$ such that $A(x)P(x)+B(x)Q(x)=1$. Then:

$$
\frac{1}{x^a(x+k)^b}=\frac{A(x)\,x^a+B(x)\,(x+k)^b}{x^a(x+k)^b}=\frac{A(x)}{(x+k)^b}+\frac{B(x)}{x^a}
$$

Expanding $A(x)$ in powers of $(x+k)$ as $A(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{b-1} a_i(x+k)^i$, and with $B(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{a-1} b_ix^i$:

$$
\frac{1}{x^a(x+k)^b}= \sum_{i=0}^{b-1} \frac{a_i}{(x+k)^{b-i}} + \sum_{i=0}^{a-1} \frac{b_i}{x^{a-i}}
$$

Comment: what about $a_i$ and $b_i?$

Comment: @AliShadhar $A(x),B(x)$ are determined using the [extended polynomial GCD algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity_and_extended_GCD_algorithm), which in turn follows from the [Euclidean division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) of polynomials. Once $A(x) = \sum \alpha_i x^i$ is determined, writing $x^i = \big((x+k)-k\big)^i$, expanding the binomial and collecting gives the expansion in powers of $(x+k)$ as $A(x) = \sum a_i (x+k)^i$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible: $\displaystyle\frac{\left(-1\right)^{a+b-1}}{n^a\left(n+k\right)^b}=\sum_{i+j=a+b}\binom{i-1}{a-1}\frac1{k^i\left(n+k\right)^j}+\sum_{i+j=a+b}\binom{j-1}{b-1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^i}{n^ik^j}$

In other words, $\displaystyle\frac{1}{n^a\left(n+k\right)^b}=-\sum_{i=a}^{a+b}\binom{i-1}{a-1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{a+b}}{k^i\left(n+k\right)^{a+b-i}}-\sum_{j=b}^{a+b}\binom{j-1}{b-1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{a+b-j}}{n^{a+b-j}k^j}$

Define $s=a+b\;$ and $\;\nu\in\{i,j\}.$ Using Cauchy product, we can rewrite this identity in terms of formal power series:

$\displaystyle n^b\left(n+k\right)^a\sum_{s=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{s-1}x^s}{\left(n\left(n+k\right)\right)^s}=\left(\sum_{\nu=0}^\infty\binom{\nu-1}{a-1}\frac{x^\nu}{k^\nu}\right)\left(\sum_{\nu=0}^\infty\frac{x^\nu}{\left(n+k\right)^\nu}\right)+\left(\sum_{\nu=0}^\infty\binom{\nu-1}{b-1}\frac{x^\nu}{k^\nu}\right)\left(\sum_{\nu=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-x\right)^\nu}{n^\nu}\right)$

This identity can be easily checked by some elementary manipulations with power series.

Comment: can you write your sums in the first line in the form of $\sum_{r=c}^d?$

Comment: done, sorry to keep you waiting

Comment: Thank you but we need to decompose $\frac1{k^i (n+k)^{a+b-i}}$ again.

Answer (score 0):

The partial fraction of :
$$\dfrac{1}{X^a(X + k)^b}$$
is :
$$\dfrac{1}{X^a(X + k)^b} = \sum_{p = 1}^a \dfrac{\alpha_p}{X^p} + \sum_{p = 1}^b \dfrac{\beta_p}{(X + k)^p}$$

Comment: Could you expand a little since the op asked for a method?

Comment: You want an example?

Comment: His answer is right. One method to obtain the decomposition(to get the values of $\alpha_p, \beta_p$ is to let the expressions be same and multiply $X^a(X+k)^b$ to both sides, and solve for each coefficient.